# Laravel 5.2 - Laravel Model With Migration with table Name Command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have 2 commands for making migration and making model.

If I run-

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=temps
```

Then I am getting a migration like this- **2016_02_09_060158_create_users_table.php**

And content inside this file is -

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('temps', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('temps');
    }
}
```

If I run this command-

```
php artisan make:model User -m
```

Then I am getting this 2 files-

**2016_02_09_060436_create_temps_table.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTempsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('temps', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('temps');
    }
}
```

**Temp.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Temp extends Model
{
    //
}
```

But I want to have a command which is a mixture of this 2 s that I can get 2 file and DB name should be included in the files (say in this case table name is *temps*).

Is there any way?

---

**Update**

I have tried this-

```
php artisan make:migration:schema create_dogs_table --schema="name:string"
```

And Found this-

[image]

Comment: To solve this problem, anyone should install the dependencies showed in the video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't understand your question but i think you want a command that generates both model and migration.

You should take a look at [Jeffery Way's Generators](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended) package.You can do this:

```
php artisan make:migration:schema create_dogs_table --schema="name:string"
```